# Why do the seats turn green?

Tags: phoenix-framework, elm

I have been following the phoenix/elm tutorial on Cultivate, I got to part 6, where the seat-toggling function is added. When I went to the generated page and clicked on the seats, they turned green. My question is "why green?". From what I can see it's not explicitly specified anywhere in the existing code so far. Am I  missing something or is this some sort of quirk?
Here is the github rep:https://github.com/CultivateHQ/seat_saver
Here is the tutorial I was following:https://github.com/CultivateHQ/seat_saver

Comment: Can you please add a link to the tutorial in the question?

Comment: @Dogbert Just did :)

Answer (score 2):

The [`Toggle Seat` Action](https://github.com/CultivateHQ/seat_saver/blob/a880c3ae2697db309fd587e01a500818b716745f/web/elm/SeatSaver.elm#L54-L61) flips the value of `occupied` field of that Seat, then the view [adds a class `occupied` or `available`](https://github.com/CultivateHQ/seat_saver/blob/a880c3ae2697db309fd587e01a500818b716745f/web/elm/SeatSaver.elm#L73-L81) to the seat depending on the value of the `occupied` field and finally the [stylesheet changes the background color](https://github.com/CultivateHQ/seat_saver/blob/2e47e185b01f79394e9c4e37a5ecb5b81f0da8f6/web/static/css/seatsaver.css#L45-L46) of the `.seat` depending on the class:

```
.available { background: #AAA; }
.occupied  { background: #99cc33; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I don't know how I missed it :P